# OR and AND conditions not returning as expected - What is best way to implement it?

Tags: javascript, operators

I have an If statement that using || with an && operator e.g if((a || b) && c) however it is only works with the first condition i.e a but not with second i.e b even though running the debugger I can see that the condition is met and it goes to the correct line of code. Is there a better way to get this to work on both conditions?

code I have now:

```
function _getCatFormGUID(catName) {
debugger;
var dept = Browser.getValue(getElement("126D81CA203C21CF014C8A3550227892FE4B4A6A"));

if((catName == '1' && dept == "Entwicklung") || (catName == '7' && dept == "Entwicklung")){
    return "A270AE7F957A74EF0842403EEA0032017567F3E8";
}

if((catName == '1' && dept != "Entwicklung") || (catName == '7' && dept != "Entwicklung")) {
    return "8EDD0768A7CDF8FD8AE90DB473F41EF0B33FA14F";
}



return "";}
```

I have tried the following also:

```
if((catName == '1'  || catName == '7') && dept == "Entwicklung"){
    return "A270AE7F957A74EF0842403EEA0032017567F3E8";
}
```

and

```
if(catName == '1' && dept == "Entwicklung"){
    return "A270AE7F957A74EF0842403EEA0032017567F3E8";
}
if(catName == '7' && dept == "Entwicklung"){
    return "A270AE7F957A74EF0842403EEA0032017567F3E8";
}
```

It only returns for catName =='1'.

Comment: What's the value which you are getting in `catName` and `dept` while debugging?

Comment: it will not work because you are returning inside the conditions, the function will terminate! If satisfies the first condition, eventually it will exit the function,

Comment: `if((catName == '1'  || catName == '7') && dept == "Entwicklung"){` should work just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have to understand how those 2 logical operators do the comparison: because your first condition `catName == '1'` is true, it will never go to second conditions from the first parenthesis nor in the second paranthesis.
Given your example, you might rewrite your logical condition from:
`if((catName == '1' && dept == "Entwicklung") || (catName == '7' && dept == "Entwicklung")){
    return "A270AE7F957A74EF0842403EEA0032017567F3E8";
}`

to
`if(dept == "Entwicklung" && catName == '1' || catName == '7'){ return something; }
}`

Comment: I'll add a comment instead of rewriting the answer, as you might not specified something important here: if you will receive both values (1 & 7), writing this logical verification, will never validate the value for 7. If you need to have 2 returned values(one for 1 and one for 7), you need to create individual `if` checks, or check the dept, and if it matche, create an array with values to compare, and return the result for the values you wanted(you can use Array map method);

Comment: But catName changes depending on a selection so how do I get around this? Do I need to create same return but under a different GUID? so instead of having one return value for 2 conditions, have 2 return values, one for each condition?

Comment: First you check the common condition. If it's meant, you check the second(catName value). But if you check this value in a dynamic manner(while checking some boxes, or changing a select) you need to run the function each time for each event.

Comment: Should it not run for each event if I have it as an Onchange event against catName?

Comment: Well the code is correct for logical verification, you might try to console log a random message, onchange event, to make sure that your function is triggered every time you change the cat value.

Comment: Definitely triggers.. I can see in debug when I toggle between catName =1 and catName = 7 (or any other status). The problem only occurs with catName == 7... for all other status it returns empty which is what is stated. I have also condition for catName == 5 which works but it returns a different GUID from 7 & 1.. Maybe I will need to have 2 separate ID for each catName 1 & 7.... will test that out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, I will write your first bit of code as bellow

```
function _getCatFormGUID(catName) {
    var dept = Browser.getValue(getElement("126D81CA203C21CF014C8A3550227892FE4B4A6A"));

    if (catName == '1' || catName == '7') {
        if(dept == 'Entwicklung'){
            return "A270AE7F957A74EF0842403EEA0032017567F3E8";
        }
        else{
            return "8EDD0768A7CDF8FD8AE90DB473F41EF0B33FA14F";
        }
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mritunjay, ran this through the debugger and it picks up catName = 7 and dept = "Entwicklung", goes to the correct return but doesn't display it. For catName = '1' is does the same steps but displays the results.